# Limit the Number of VMs of a Given Type, Folder, or Resource Pool in vCenter

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Is it possible to limit the number of VMs of a given type within vCenter?  When I say a given type, as I know there's no specific "type" associated with a VM, it could be as simple as the # of VMs within a folder or within a resource pool.  I have been looking through the documentation, the vSphere client interface, and the VIM25 SDK for some time and haven't been able to determine if this is possible.  The only limitation enforcement that I've seen up to this point has been related to resource pools and CPU/Memory allocations.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you give a better idea of what's driving this requirement?

Comment: I'm trying to limit the number of VMs produced from a give template to help enforce OS licensing.  My preference is for this to be managed from within vCenter if possible, however if that's not feasible then I'll probably continue down the wrapped vCenter API approach.  I honestly didn't believe that it was possible, but I figured it'd be worth throwing the question out there to make sure.

Comment: Curious... are you using vCenter Chargeback at all?

Comment: No we're not, nor did I come across it when I was looking before.  I'll have to look into it, as it sounds like it has some facilities that might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Chopper3's comment, a combination of vCloud Director (try to go for the >=5.1 installs, not 1.5), vCenter Orchestrator, and a good message queue setup would get you pretty close to where you're looking to be on this.

vCloud >=5.1 allows for generic metadata to be applied to just about every object one can create in vCloud Director.  That includes Edge Gateways, External Networks, etc. One could also point their vCloud Director installation at a message queue (although VMware seems to prefer RabbitMQ) and control MACD changes to the environment with the blocking tasks one can set up through vCD. Orchestrator acts as a nice hub for pulling things out of the MQ, and doing "actions" with them.

To agree with everyone else though, with just vCenter, you're going to have a pretty rough time with this, unless you wrap around the vCenter/vSphere API some kind of message queuing logic, and maybe use that comments field for the VM within vCenter/vSphere.

Answer (score 3):

It's only possible by using vCloud Director or some other form of orchestration to create the VMs, not once they're already built. Obviously you could script something but nothing out of the box sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin functionality to enforce such a limit.
The best thing you can do is to monitor these numbers through an external script (e.g. PowerCLI) and have that trigger an alert if a limit is reached.